# Should ideal dietary fibre quantities relate to the amount of food one consumes?

Tags: nutrition, digestion, colon

Typically advice seems (for the non-medical professional) to state recommended dietary fibre in absolute mass.

I wonder if it is more accurate to state recommended dietary fibre in terms of the quantity of food being eaten? Perhaps as a percentage of the mass?

The reasoning behind this is simply that dietary fibre seems less to do with obtaining nutrients, but more to do with the physical consistency of food / bolus / chyme.

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations for dietary fiber intake are usually based on **age/calorie intake:**

The [Dietary Guidelines for Americans 2015-2020 (p.97)](https://health.gov/dietaryguidelines/2015/resources/2015-2020_Dietary_Guidelines.pdf) recommendation for men age 19-30 (2,400 - 3,000 Cal range) is 33.6 g and for girls age 4-8 (1,200 Cal) is 16.8 g of fiber per day.

According to [Food and Drug Administration](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/InteractiveNutritionFactsLabel/factsheets/Dietary_Fiber.pdf), the "daily value" for dietary fiber in a 2,000 Cal diet is 25 g.

It may be more important to think about the soluble/insoluble fiber ratio: Most metabolic health effects suggested so far are associated with soluble fiber and bowel regularity with insoluble fiber.

Comment: Please note that the above references are US centric. Other countries have varied recommendations.

Comment: I was not trying to emphasize the exact amounts but on what are recommendations based on and what do you want to achieve with fiber consumption. The recommendation from [European Science Hub](https://ec.europa.eu/jrc/en/health-knowledge-gateway/promotion-prevention/nutrition/fibre#_Tocch4) is 25-38 g fiber/day for adults, so not really different from the US.

Comment: It wasn't a criticism, just a note for future browsers. :) They are fairly similar for most countries that I've looked at.